# How to print numbers on a new line in python

Tags: python

A program accepts a number of inputs, for instance numbers or integers, how do you print each and every one of them on a new line.
Eg. I enter this 2,4,5,2,38.
The program should display each one on a new line as this.

```
Item = input ("Enter your number")
 #user enters the following numbers 5,2,6,3,2
 #print out each number on a new line 

# output
5
2
6
3
2
```

All saved i one variable.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ronakg well I tried storing all the numbers in one variable and tried to print them out,but it seem to only print the last number i imputed.

Comment: How does the user inputs the numbers? separated with a comma or a space?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a simple for loop that iterates over the input and prints it

```
data = raw_input('enter ints').split(',')

for n in data:
    if n.isdigit():
        print n
```

Note if you are using Pyhon 3.x, you need to use `input` instead of `raw_input`

The first row assigns user input data to `data` variable and splits items by space. (You can change this tow ',' instead)
The for loop does iteration on every item in that list and checks if it is a digit. Because the list elements are strings, we can use `isdigit()` method of string to test it.

```
>>> '5'.isdigit()
True
>>> '12398'.isdigit()
True
```

---

If you want to do it in another way, maybe using `'\n'.join(data)` method, which will join the list elements and join them with '\n'.

```
>>> inpu = raw_input('enter ints\n').split(',')
>>> inpu = [c.strip() for c in inpu]
>>> print '\n'.join(inpu)
1
2
3
4
```

This is actually the better way to go, as it is simpler than a for loop.

Comment: You also use `print(n)` if you use Python 3.x.

Comment: ok is there not any way to do this without using a for loop. or could you elaborate further

Comment: You are only printing digits, not integers >= 10. The OP wanted a comma-separated list of integers.

Comment: @SamJereriaManuel there is, using `join()` method. I've updated my answer to include that solution and elaborate on the for loop one.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE it does tests if the string item represents a digit. I've added an example of four-digit string check using `isdigit()`

Comment: Yes I know. My remarks was valid until you edited and add the `split`: your iteration was over the characters, not the list.

Answer (score 0):

By typing in `print()` in python it will move to the next line. If it is a list you can do

```
for num in list:
    print(num)
    print()
```

You want to replace "list" with the name of your list.

You can also type in `\n` in your print function in quotes to move to a new line.

Comment: print prints new line by default

Comment: Ok what of if the are ints not string, and after each input when am done with the loop thus entering an amount of ints I want, it should display every single int i entered in a different line.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are separated by a comma, you can split them by that comma, then join them by a new line:

```
>>> Item = input ("Enter your numbers: ")
Enter your numbers: 5,2,6,3,2
>>> Result = '\n'.join(Item.split(','))
>>> print(Result)
5
2
6
3
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a comma-separated list of integers, one integer at each line, you can do:

```
items = input('Enter a comma-separated list of integers: ')
print(items.replace(",", "\n"))
```

Example:

```
Enter a comma-separated list of integers:  1,13,5
1
13
5
```

You can improve by accepting ";" instead of "," and optional spaces using RegEx:

```
import re

items = input('Enter a comma-separated list of integers: ')
print(re.sub(r"[,;]\s*", "\n", items))
```

Example:

```
Enter a comma-separated list of integers:  2, 4, 5; 2,38
2
4
5
2
38
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like I'm too late to the print party  :)
this can work for you too ... wrap it in a function ideally

```
# assuming STDIN like: "2,4,5,2,38,42 23|26, 24| 31"

split_by = [","," ","|"]
i_n_stdin = input()
for i in split_by:
    i_n_stdin = i_n_stdin.split(i)
    i_n_stdin = " ".join(i_n_stdin)
    #print(i_n_stdin)
for i in i_n_stdin.split():
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print in the new line by using by defining **end** parameter as '**\n'** (for new line) i.e **print(x,end='\n')**

```
>>> x=[1,2,3,4]
>>> for i in x:
   print(i,end='\n')
```

**output**

```
  1
  2
  3
  4
```

you can use **help** function in python

```
>>> help(print)

Help on built-in function print in module builtins:

print(...)
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
Optional keyword arguments:
file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.x

```
items = input('Numbers:').split(',')   # input returns a string
[print(x) for x in items]
```

Python 2.x

```
items = input('Numbers:')   # input returns a tuple
# you can not use list comprehension here in python 2,
# cause of print is not a function  
for x in items: print x
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set variable `end = '\n'`
and print your numbers like:

```
print(" " + str(num1) + end, str(num2) + end, str(num3) + end)
```